# Play video after startup from sdcard

Tags: android, video, playback, android-sdcard, autorun

I have an app which is autostarting via BroadcastReceiver and is set as a homescreen on Android 2.3.3. API10 on an HTC Desire HD.

The app should play a video repeatedly right after starting, but as the sdcard is not ready it kills the application with a force close error message which doesn't go away.

At least I think it is because of the sdcard.

In the background, the homescreen restarts but the error message doesn't go away, it would be no problem if it would disappear a few seconds later, but it would be even greater if it wouldn't appear at all..

can you help me?
thanks!

edit #1:
this checks if the sdcard is ready. i only need read access..

```
static public boolean hasStorage(boolean requireWriteAccess) {

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    Log.v("tomi", "storage state is " + state);

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        if (requireWriteAccess) {
            boolean writable = checkFsWritable();
            Log.v("tomi", "storage writable is " + writable);
            return writable;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else if (!requireWriteAccess && Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do you have a solution for this?

First, you should not need *both* "autostarting via BroadcastReceiver" and "set as a homescreen". One should suffice, preferably the latter.

Once the activity launches, it can check `Environment` to see if external storage is ready. If not, it can register a receiver for `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` to find out when external storage becomes ready. Once it is ready -- and only at that point -- it can try to play the video.

Comment: Hi, i need autostart and homescreen replacement so users have no access to the device and cant manipulate it. (its a kiosk app). i tried to wait for the sdcard via the code i'll update on the first post.

Comment: @antion: A kiosk app should work OK as just a replacement home screen, though bear in mind anyone can remove your app if the reboot in safe mode.

Comment: ah okay a homescreen starts automatically anyways is what you are suggesting? geez i'll try that maybe it solves all my problems ;)

Comment: @antion: "a homescreen starts automatically anyways is what you are suggesting?" -- yes.

Comment: thanks. it does work and start automatically. still i get an error after booting up which force closes my app. i cannot debug this in eclipse as it only happens after booting and there is no debug possibility present. afaik. thanks

Comment: @antion: Your stack trace will still be logged to LogCat and visible in the LogCat view in Eclipse.

Comment: thanks again, i had to click pause on the logcat like crazy but then there it was, a not found class now it starts nicely :)